# Locate number string in Excel array?

Tags: excel

I have an array of numbers in Excel beginning in B2 as follows:

```
CA.CAD.CP.0.0.0.0.1.CY
CA.CAD.CP.0.0.0.0.2.CY
CA.CAD.CP.0.0.0.1.0.CY
CA.CAD.CP.0.0.0.2.0.CY
CA.CAD.CP.0.0.3.0.0.CY
CA.CAD.CP.0.0.0.6.0.CY
CA.CAD.OIS.0.0.0.1.0.CY
CA.CAD.OIS.0.0.0.2.0.CY
CA.CAD.OIS.0.0.0.3.0.CY
CA.CAD.OIS.0.0.6.0.0.CY
CA.CAD.OIS.0.0.0.9.0.CY
CA.CAD.OIS.1.0.0.0.0.CY
CA.CAD.ONT.0.0.0.1.0.CY
CA.CAD.ONT.0.0.0.2.0.CY
CA.CAD.ONT.0.0.0.3.0.CY
CA.CAD.ONT.0.0.6.0.0.CY
CA.CAD.ONT.1.0.0.0.0.CY
```

for several thousand rows. All of them follow this exact format. The numbers represent a date format; D.W.F.M.Y. So 0.0.0.5.0 means 5 months, for example.

I want to find all instances where the date value is "F", meaning all instances of "xx.xxx.xxx.0.0.x.0.0".

What is the best way to do this? I have tried using the FIND function but I think there might be a better way to search for this string.

Comment: Why does the find not work for you?

Comment: Could you also provide some data that had the "F", none of the above appear to have it.

Comment: i am not looking for one specific string (for instance 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3 etc are all admissible values) so FIND did not work; is there a way to fix it to accommodate that?

Comment: edited it to add data with F

Comment: If your dates are *always* formatted like the above, you could pull the date out with `Mid()`, no?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion, I didn't word this very well. The dates are formatted D.W.F.M.Y ; so a value of F would mean a string corresponding for 0.0.1.0.0, 0.0.4.0.0, 0.0.6.0.0 etc. The third value is the F value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return True/False based on whether the middle, or "F" position is anything but 0 or not:

```
=--MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",REPT(" ",99)),5*99,99)<>0
```

[image]

Comment: what does the "--" before MID in the formula do?

Comment: It changes the result from a string to a number. @beeba

Comment: I've seen this sort of method before and it clearly works well but haven't really understood it. I think I've got it now - if you choose a number of spaces much bigger than the string itself and do the substitution, each block of (say) 99 characters contains a few spaces, a string or number, then a lot of spaces and on the next step you just drop the spaces using TRIM or converting to a number. Sorry, just thinking aloud.

Comment: @TomSharpe yes when returning a string it would need to be wrapped with TRIM to remove the extra spaces or it would have a lot.  It gives us a large target to use as a split.  With it being numbers using mathematical function causes excel to automatically remove the space as it tries to make the string a number.

Answer (score 3):

With data starting in **A2**, in **B2** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,".",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across and then down:

[image]

Then set an AutoFilter on column **G** to display non-zero values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought to use Word's Find feature?  I understand it's in excel - but copy and paste data into Word - it's Find capabilities allow you to search for variables even formatting and special characters including tabs, and punctuation - you can use the Find/Replace feature to have it perform some special maneuvers to mark your text before simply copy/paste *special* back into excel when finished with Word's special unique features - it's find/replace capabilities are stronger than any other Office program